# Using CloudKit console to add image data to a record

Tags: cloudkit

I am trying to set up a small CloudKit database using the console app to use during development of my app.  The database has just a few records with only two fields each: a string as a name and an asset which is supposed to refer to an image.  When adding a new record I click in the image field the console lets me pick a file, say "DSC_0175.jpeg" and "DSC_0175.jpeg (2823.05KB) ready to upload"  appears in the field.  (I get the same if I drag and drop the image file into the field.) However when I click Save, I get an error message at the bottom of the record panel saying "Load failed" and while the record gets saved with its name field, the image field is empty in the resulting record.  Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is not a code problem.  I'm trying to use the web based console app to create the initial database without using code.  Can we paste screen shots here?